# Which Mistborn Era 2 nobles are descended from Mistborn Era 1 characters?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, wax-wayne-novels

As with Wax being a descendant of Breeze, which families in Mistborn Era 2 can trace lineage back to characters from Mistborn Era 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you've said, the [Ladrian family](https://coppermind.net/wiki/House_Ladrian) ([Wax](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Waxillium_Ladrian), hissister [Telsin](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Telsin_Ladrian), uncle [Edwarn (Suit)](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Edwarn_Ladrian), and Edwarn's son [Hinston](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Hinston_Ladrian)) are descendants of [Breeze](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Breeze) and [Allrianne Cett](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Allrianne_Cett).

There are other members of the Cett family alive at the time of Era 2, Lady [Aving](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Aving_Cett) and her heir [Westweather](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Westweather_Cett).

A number of other noble houses have survived:

- [House Tekiel](https://coppermind.net/wiki/House_Tekiel) - Built [Tekiel Tower](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Tekiel_Tower)
- [House Entrone](https://coppermind.net/wiki/House_Entrone)
- [House Erikell](https://coppermind.net/wiki/House_Erikell)
- [House Venture](https://coppermind.net/wiki/House_Venture) - [Douglas Venture](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Douglas_Venture)
- [House Yomen](https://coppermind.net/wiki/House_Yomen) - [Joshin Yomen](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Joshin_Yomen)

There is also [Claude Aradel](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Claude_Aradel) the Constable-General turned Governor of [Elendel](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Elendel) who is (by Word of Brandon) a descendant of [Goradel](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Goradel)

Comment: just fyi I don't know if this is absolutely exhaustive, I just did a quick pass over the pages on the coppermind (mainly the noble houses)